# Solutions for forced damping

Tags: differential-equations, vibrations

What is the real physical meaning of finding the solutions for 2nd order differential equation. Like in forced damping system.

Comment: Isn't it finding the variable as a function of the other? Like, $d^2x/dt^2=f(x,t)\to x(t)$?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that the equation is an analog of the real world. The equation and the coefficients come from simple physical measurements like a spring constant or the flexing of strip of metal. Measurements also show that for motions that are not too great, assumptions of linear behavior are reasonable. Once you have an equation that looks like it fits the physical system - that perhaps takes into account position and velocity and acceleration with respect to time, you apply the results from the theory of differential equations, such as adding two solutions to get a third solution. And this works really well up to a point.

As you get closer to reality and try to account for losses in springs or air resistance as the square of velocity, and temperature effects, the equation will go from very difficult to unsolvable. Numerical methods and analog computers can be used at this point to get results for particular initial conditions.

So, the DEQ is a model of a system. If the model is correct, you can analyze the behavior. You tend to get exponential increase or decrease or oscillation growing or damped or constant. Most of nature works that way on some scale.